# Django: Class based view form_class choice

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I've a single View, that can be called with or without the **label_rif** attribute, based on this I can switch the form_class and template?

```
class LabelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.Label

    if self.kwargs['label_rif'] > 0:
        form_class = LabelForm
        template_name = 'AUTO_form.html'
    else:
        form_class = LabelManForm
        template_name = 'MAN_form.html'
```

I've tried to insert the form_class without success in the method

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(LabelCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()

    if self.kwargs['label_rif']:
             form_class = LabelForm
```

Or should I define another separate view?
I want to keep it DRY, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one view by overriding `get_form_class` and `get_template_names`:

```
class LabelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.Label

    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.kwargs['label_rif'] > 0:
            return LabelForm
        else:
            return LabelManForm

    def get_template_names(self):
        # Note this returns a list, not a string
        if self.kwargs['label_rif'] > 0:
            return ['AUTO_form.html']
        else:
            return ['MAN_form.html']
```

Depending on your url config, I think that two views might be more readable in this case. You only need to override the attributes that differ, so it is still DRY.

```
class LabelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.Label

    form_class = LabelForm
    template_name = 'AUTO_form.html'

class ManLabelCreateView(LabelCreateView):
    form_class = LabelManForm
    template_name = 'MAN_form.html'
```